# Is there a correlation between arthritis and diastolic blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure, arthritis, osteoarthritis

Is there a correlation between arthritis and diastolic blood pressure?

i.e if diastolic is high you get arthritic symptoms or vice versa.

Comment: Why do you suspect there might be? Is this something you suspect that you have experienced? Did a doctor tell you about this? Did you read it in a journal article?